# Pin To Start In Proper Group Powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

Given the group information shown below. How can I pin to a specific group (row and column as well) using powershell?

```
 <start:Group Name="Create">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsLive.Calendar" />
```

Here is the base code im using

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$appname,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

Instead of asking so many questions about little bits of a bad solution for your problem, why not ask your real question?

> If you want to know what apps are pinned to your Start Menu you might
>   go ahead and export the Start Menu Layout xml. Here you will see an
>   entry shown in the question that gives an AUMID of the pinned item. **I
>   want to pin my pinned shortcuts from one computer to another computer**.

That's what [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556089/convert-aumid-to-application-name-c-sharp#comment78110960_45556089).

Instead of asking *at least* **four** questions<sup>1</sup> about your strange approach at solving this problem just ask your real question and get a real answer:

Just like you used `Export-StartLayout` to get the layout XML from one computer use `Import-StartLayout` to set the start layout from the XML on the other computer.

---

<sup>1</sup> (1) [Parse Xml For Nodes Within Nodes C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493364/parse-xml-for-nodes-within-nodes-c-sharp) (2) [Convert AUMID to Application Name C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556089/convert-aumid-to-application-name-c-sharp) (3) [Pin To Start In Proper Group Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599512/pin-to-start-in-proper-group-powershell) (this one), and (4) [Pinning To Start Items In AppData Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622596/pinning-to-start-items-in-appdata-folder)

Comment: I want to take all the shortcuts from my computer and put them on another computer. I have the layout xml from the first computer. I want them in the same group structure. There is more to it. I cannot simply import to the new computer with a simple powershell command. This does not work given my scenrio. Must be done manually

Comment: @nlstack01: You say there is more to it but don't say what's more. You say you have a mysterious scenario for which this [XY](http://xyproblem.info/)ing is legitimate, but you don't tell us what it is. I say there's nothing more to it and it's just a waste of time. Use `Import-StartLayout` and stop wasting everyone's (including your own) time.